# Constant try catch with ES6?

Tags: constants, ecmascript-6

I try to use `const` all the time, but often I find myself in a position, where I have to use `let`.

For example:

```
let value

try {
  value = couldFail()
} catch(e) {
  value = etc()
}

doSomethingWith(value)
```

Is there a general way to restructure such things?

-- Edit --

An idea I had:

```
const tryCatch = (a, b) => {
  try { return a() }
  catch(e) { return b(e) }
}

const value = tryCatch(couldFail, etc)
```

Could this bring any problems?

Comment: `tryCatch` seems to be totally appropriate. It's the functional way of doing this.

Comment: A function wrapper will be necessary, you could do `Promise.resolve().then(() => a()).catch(err => b(err)).then(value => doSomething(value))` if you don't mind it being async, or even `Promise.resolve().then(a).catch(b).then(doSomethingWith)`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use const since the value may be assigned first in the try clause and later in the catch clause. If you absolutely want your variable to be const, you can create a temporary variable that you assign in your try and catch clause, and add a `finally` clause where you assign the temporary variable to your const variable.